# Ionic 3 - Ion-Item Clickable

Tags: html, ionic, ionic3, angular

Ao utilizar a diretiva ION-ITEM dentro de ION-LIST, não é possível clicar em nenhum elemento que esteja dentro, ex.: um campo de text (input), quando testamos com o emulador iOS no Chrome.

```
<ion-list class="list-form">
  <ion-item tappable>
    <ion-label floating>
      <ion-icon name="mail" item-start class="text-white"></ion-icon>
      Email
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>
      <ion-icon name="lock" item-start class="text-white"></ion-icon>
      Senha
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Você quer clicar nos itens?

Comment: sim, no android e no navegador web funciona, só no iOS que não.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar ionFocus em vez de click.

```
<ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" (ionFocus)="doSomething()"></ion-input>
```

Tem várias issues abertas sobre esse problema, creio que possa ser resolvido em uma versão futura. O problema não é o item e sim o input dentro do mesmo.

Comment: Mas eu não quero chamar uma função no Focus... na verdade eu nem consigo dar foco no campo!

Comment: Não entendi, achei que seu problema era com algum evento de click no componente. Você diz que os componentes estão congelados entao?

Comment: Exatamente, eu não consigo nem clicar dentro de qualquer elemento dentro do ion-item! Realmente como voce disse o iOS tem um bug nesse sentido!

Comment: @mcamara Você já tentou atualizar sua versão do ionic?

Comment: Sim... Mas acho que consegui resolver o problema, tive que tirar o ion-list :(

Comment: Entendi, @mcamara. Se resolveu seu problema, adiciona uma resposta, dessa forma vc pode ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema

Comment: mas eu resolvendo meu problema não significa que está certo, concorda? Uma vez que foi só uma forma de contornar o problema!

Comment: Você pode dizer isso quando for responder, que como não achou uma solução resolveu fazer do jeito que está. Creio que é melhor do que ficar sem resposta. E também faz sentido, pois talvez seja mesmo um bug, como dissemos, tem várias issues abertas com problemas iguais ou semelhantes.